# VBA UserForms - comparind data in userform

Tags: vba, userform

I have two files. One file is with specification, second with the reuslts. I've created UserForm where I can compare if result is within the specified range & result is assessed as OK or NOK.

[Spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EiRw.jpg)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6bIE.jpg)

Results & specification is saved from excel to tables & from table are populated into UserForm. During this, I met situation where randowm result (not the same) is within the range of specification but final Judgment is NOK. All data (spec& results) are in "General" format.

[UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl2pT.jpg)

When I will write the same result manualy, then Judgment is OK. I have 14 windows which are working with below the same code (numbers are just different)

```
Private Sub txtVal14_AfterUpdate()

Val14 = CofC_FORM.txtVal14.Value

If CofC_FORM.Test14 <> "" Then

    If CofC_FORM.Val14 >= CofC_FORM.Min14 Then
        
        If CofC_FORM.Val14 <= CofC_FORM.Max14 Then
            
            CofC_FORM.Jud14.Caption = "OK"
            CofC_FORM.Jud14.BackColor = RGB(102, 255, 51)
            
        Else: CofC_FORM.Jud14.Caption = "NOK"
              CofC_FORM.Jud14.BackColor = RGB(255, 51, 0)
        End If
        
    Else: CofC_FORM.Jud14.Caption = "NOK"
          CofC_FORM.Jud14.BackColor = RGB(255, 51, 0)
              
    End If
    
Else: CofC_FORM.Jud14.Caption = ""

End If
```

End Sub

I thought there are string valuse to compare & I implemented in the step before below code to change string to the number:

```
For Each r In Sheets(i).Range("G23:G28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    r.Select
                    r.NumberFormat = "0.00"
                    String1 = r.Value
                    String1 = Replace(String1, ",", ".")
                    r.Value = CSng(String1)
                Next r
```

Can someone help me ? Do you have any idea what could be the problem as I think, aboce code is OK.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers, and as string `105` is smaller than `50` (because 1 is smaller than 5).

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit your question and add the details there.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve with modifying your *cell* content. Your cells contains numbers, that's fine. You need to convert the content of the text boxes into numbers. Search for functions like `Val()`, `CLng()` and `CDbl()`

Comment: Thank you for advice. I sorted this issue to change CSng() for each label & textbox which is involved for data comparison.